# How do you build the Pion mediadevices webrtc example?

Tags: c, go, webrtc, raspberry-pi-zero

I was checking out [Pion Mediadevices](https://github.com/pion/mediadevices/tree/master/examples/webrtc) and trying to cross-compile the webrtc example for a rasperry pi zero from my windows computer. When I try to build the example though, I get these errors from Windows command prompt:

```
    # github.com/pion/mediadevices/pkg/codec/mmal
..\..\pkg\codec\mmal\params.go:30:9: undefined: newEncoder
# github.com/pion/mediadevices/pkg/driver/microphone
..\..\pkg\driver\microphone\microphone.go:27:10: undefined: malgo.AllocatedContext
..\..\pkg\driver\microphone\microphone.go:34:2: undefined: malgo.DeviceInfo
..\..\pkg\driver\microphone\microphone.go:40:13: undefined: malgo.InitContext
..\..\pkg\driver\microphone\microphone.go:40:36: undefined: malgo.ContextConfig
..\..\pkg\driver\microphone\microphone.go:78:25: undefined: malgo.DeviceInfo
```

Also because the program is for the pi zero I edited the import section to have "github.com/pion/mediadevices/pkg/codec/mmal" and commented out the x264 import.
What is the correct way to build this example?

Edit: Upon further investigation, I found that the error message above:

```
 ..\..\pkg\codec\mmal\params.go:30:9: undefined: newEncoder
```

correlates to a call to the function newEncoder which is declared in a seperate go file, mmal.go, in the same folder as params.go. Both of these files have `package mmal` at the top before their imports and the folder they're contained in is also called mmal. Is there any problems there causing the function to not be viewable to params.go?

Comment: I am tagging this C as its clearly a CGO issue, for anyone else that might want to walk into that minefield https://github.com/pion/mediadevices/tree/master/pkg/codec/mmal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mediadevices currently uses cgo to give us access to camera/microphone and codecs. Cross-compiling in cgo is possible but you would very likely need to cross-compile mmal codec as a static library yourself, but this requires access to the source code.

Unfortunately, mmal is not an open-source library. Therefore, the only option left is to compile the library on the raspberry pi since mmal should be installed on your system already.

Note: I'm the mediadevices author .

Comment: Thank you for the answer that makes sense! (and thank you for the api!)